# PHP - MySQLi Insert is not working for User Register

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I am trying to do a simple insert for a user sign up. I am using the following PHP code for this.

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
require 'variables.php';

// Set variables
$tbl_name = 'users';
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$checkpw = $_POST['checkpw'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];

$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
$checkpw = stripslashes($checkpw);
$checkpw = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['checkpw']);

function mempty()
{
foreach(func_get_args() as $arg)
    if(!empty($arg)) {
        continue;
    }
    else {
        header('location:register.php?msg=failed');
    }

}
// Check if variables are empty.
mempty($username);
mempty($password);
mempty($checkpw);
mempty($dob);

if (strcmp ($password, $checkpw) == 0) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username,password,email,dob) VALUES ($username,$password,$email,$dob)";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Registered Successfully!";
    }
}
?>
```

The $_POST comes from an HTML form, where I don't believe the problem exists, but I'll show you it anyway just in case.

```
<form method="post" action="initsec.php">
<p class="reg">Username:</p>
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"><br />
<?php if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == 'pws') { echo "Passwords do not match!<br />"; } ?>
<p class="reg">Password:</p>
<input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"><br />
<p>Confirm Password:</p>
<input type="password" name="checkpw" id="checkpw" placeholder="Re-enter Password"><br />
<p>Email Address:</p>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br />
<p>Date of Birth:</p>
<input type="date" name="dob" id="dob"><br />
<input name="register" type="submit" value="Register" class="register">
</form>
```

The problem is that the record is not being inserted.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: `($username,$password,$email,$dob)` quote those. `mysqli_error($conn)` would have signaled the syntax error.

Comment: @kingkero  The problem is that the record is not being inserted into the database.

Comment: [Notice the upvotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104467/php-mysqli-insert-is-not-working-for-user-register#comment46439008_29104467). Do that. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

Comment: @ThomasYamakaitis: You should add a disclaimer to your form which tells your users that you are harvesting their passwords in plain text.

Comment: Alternatively scrap it and use a prepared statement with bound parameters/values instead of interpolating variables into an SQL query string.

Comment: Sidenote: You do plan on storing hashed passwords, instead of plain text, correct?

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in. At the very least when using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query.

Comment: @tadman - oh I dunno, writing a basic login system **is** pretty easy (full RBAC'd CMS not so much) and shouldn't really require throwing an entire framework at it - but I agree that there are lots of ways to get it severely wrong ... ask Sony.

Comment: @CD001 That's what I mean. It's super easy to get so very wrong that your access control system has the opposite effect: Instead of keeping people out, it allows them to do *anything* they want. Don't think "throwing a framework" at something is a bad thing, it's how modern web sites are built.

Comment: @tadman - not saying a framework is a bad thing per se - but depending on what you're doing it could well be using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: @CD001 Writing low-level code is like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Frameworks make it *stupidly* easy to do simple stuff. Why would you ignore that? You go low-level when that doesn't cut it.

Comment: @tadman it comes at a cost though - you don't *need* the overhead of a framework to do simple things and Laravel isn't the fastest PHP framework (you'd want Phalcon for that) - I'm not ignoring the fact that using a framework can speed up development time, help reduce errors or make life easier (once you've learnt the framework) but I'm also not ignoring the fact that they add an overhead to your application - IMO the complexity of the application should inform your decision as to whether to use a framework or not.

Comment: I have this conversation all the time with PHP people, and PHP people only. No Ruby, Python or NodeJS developer in their right mind would ever think of doing something ground-up, they'd use a framework, even a small one, to get going. I'm not saying use Laravel for everything, but at least use **something**. Computers are so crazy fast these days I highly doubt the performance penalty of a framework will even matter 99 times out of 100. If you need speed, you can always optimize if and when you have that problem.

Comment: The #1 reason for using a framework is it provides you with a good example to work from, something that would've prevented this train-wreck of bad practices from ever occurring. People tend to make more minor mistakes with a framework to guide them, and when they do have problems there's a community there to back them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues.  I think your main one is your SQL statement:

```
"INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username,password,email,dob) 
VALUES ($username,$password,$email,$dob)"
```

The string values probably will need to be quoted (as noted by @Fred -ii- in the comments):

```
"INSERT INTO $tbl_name (username,password,email,dob) 
VALUES ('$username','$password','$email','$dob')"
```

I also don't think this function is going to work as you expect it to:

```
function mempty()
{
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        if(!empty($arg)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            header('location:register.php?msg=failed');
        }
    }
}
```

I added curly braces around the `foreach`, I suggest you do the same for easier readability.  Also, if you do not explicitly `exit` after issuing a `header()` redirect, the script will continue (causing all of your failures to *also* attempt to be inserted into the database), so I would also suggest you do that.  Since you're `continue`ing in the loop, you can omit the else altogether for brevity:

```
function mempty()
{
    foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
        if(!empty($arg)) {
            continue;
        } 

        header('location:register.php?msg=failed');
        exit();
    }
}
```

Since you're using `func_get_args` in the function, you can pass in any number of arguments, reducing the number of function calls you're making:

```
mempty($username, $password, $checkpw, $dob);
```